# Регулярные выражения JS, экранировка цифр

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Помогите пожалуйста, какую функцию выполняют экранированные числа в регулярках js(\1 типо этого), если можно с примером.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это обратные ссылки. 
Вне символьного класса обратный слеш с последующей цифрой больше нуля (и, возможно, последующими цифрами) интерпретируется как ссылка на предшествующую захватывающую подмаску, предполагая, что соответствующее количество предшествующих открывающих круглых скобок присутствует.

```js
let str = "sense and sensibility, sense and responsibility, response and responsibility"
    

console.log( str.match(/(sens|respons)e and \1ibility/g) );

// sense and sensibility
// response and responsibility
```

смотреть [здесь](https://regex101.com/r/7T8I8X/1)